# Month Year In String to Local Date

Tags: java, java-8, localdate

I am trying to parse some date-string into a date value, however, using the below code, I am getting an exception:

**My Code**

```
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
          .parseCaseInsensitive()
          .append(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM-uuuu"))
          .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1)
          .toFormatter(Locale.ENGLISH);

         LocalDate KFilter = null;
         KFilter = YearMonth.parse("July-2021", formatter).atDay(1)
```

**The error log is**

```
java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text 'July-2021' could not be parsed at index 3
```

Comment: When you use `parseDefaulting(ChronoField.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1)`, there is no need to go the `YearMonth` detour. You can simply use `LocalDate kFilter = LocalDate.parse("Jul-2021", formatter);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The format should match.
Try this.

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
        .parseCaseInsensitive()
        .append(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM-uuuu"))
        .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1)
        .toFormatter(Locale.ENGLISH);
    
    LocalDate KFilter = null;
    KFilter = YearMonth.parse("Jul-2021", formatter).atDay(1);
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the format is the problem :
"MMM-uuuu" isn't compatible with the string "july" so at the index 3 'y' it was expecting the '-'

Answer (score 1):

**Use Jul-2021 instead of July-2021**

```
LocalDate KFilter = null;
         KFilter = YearMonth.parse("Jul-2021", formatter).atDay(1)
```